# Iam getting the about:blank&utm_content=firstrun url when launching firefox through eclipse in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
package packageselenium;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
public class Login {
static String URL = ExcelUtil.readSpecificCell("C:\\Users\\Rama\\Downloads\\Eclipse_Practice\\SeleniumDay1\\Newfolder\\TestData.xlsx", "Sheet1", "URL");
public static WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     driver=WebDriverUtilities.openbrowser(driver);
     driver.navigate().to(URL);
    // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
     //Thread.sleep(1000);
     //driver.get(URL);
     System.out.println("Entered URL as"+URL);
    return; 
}
}
```

Able to launch browser .but url which i have given in the Excel sheet is "https://www.gmail.com".when im debugging the able to get URL Value.But after launching the browser able to see "about:blank&utm_content=firstrun" instead of "https://www.gmail.com".

Comment: Update selenium latest jar file

Comment: I am using latest selenium jars only.Still able to see same url "about:blank&utm_content=firstrun"

Comment: Can you check it by passing hard code url?

Comment: Yes ,able to see https://www.gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and let me know if you are able to print url on console.

```
package packageselenium;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
public class Login {
static String URL;
public static WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
URL = ExcelUtil.readSpecificCell("C:\\Users\\Rama\\Downloads\\Eclipse_Practice\\SeleniumDay1\\Newfolder\\TestData.xlsx", "Sheet1", "URL");
System.out.println("application URL "+URL)
driver=WebDriverUtilities.openbrowser(driver);
 driver.navigate().to(URL);
// driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
 //Thread.sleep(1000);
 //driver.get(URL);
 System.out.println("Entered URL as"+URL);
return; 
 }
}
```

Comment: Im able to see below errorapplication URL return Value
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at packageselenium.Login1.main(Login1.java:13)

Comment: so how you know that readSpecificCell function is working and you are able to get url value

Comment: Sorry..i have not changed the path.Now i have changed in the console able to see application URL s
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at packageselenium.Login1.main(Login1.java:13)

Comment: So for which line code you are getting nullpointer exception ?

Comment: driver.navigate().to(URL);

Comment: It means your WebDriverUtilities.openbrowser(driver) not returning webdriver object, versify it

Comment: public class WebDriverUtilities {
 static String URL  = ExcelUtil.readSpecificCell("C:\\Users\\Rama\\Downloads\\Eclipse_Practice\\SeleniumDay1\\Newfolder\\TestData.xlsx", "Sheet1", "URL");
public static WebDriver driver;
 public static WebDriver openbrowser(WebDriver driver) {
  driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  driver.get(URL);
   System.out.println("Entered URL as"+URL);
  return null;
 } 
}

Comment: After changing the code in the webdriver utilities it is working .when im using driver.get(UR) in the login1.java class not working.please  let me know why it is not working in the login1.java class